# PHP using c# DLL parameters type issues

Tags: c#, php, windows, dll

I can't call my c# function from PHP because some parameters type are wrong

I implemented my C# dll successfully. I can create my C# object and call my method like this in PHP with the following code below.

This is com_print_typeinfo detail :

```
function GetAuthorisationNo(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  // &$systemNumber,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  // &$systemVersion,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  // &$SizeOfKey,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BOOL [11]  // &$EncryptionRequired,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  // &$EncryptionMethod,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  // &$NumComponents,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_SAFEARRAY [27]  // &$ComponentBitPositions,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_SAFEARRAY [27]  // &$ComponentBitWidths,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_SAFEARRAY [27]  // &$ComponentValues,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_SAFEARRAY [27]  // &$ComponentDescriptions
)
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
$data = 10;
$val = true;
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];
$array3 = [];
$array4 = [];
$this->licenceManager = new COM('mydll.Licence');
$this->licenceManager->GetAuthorisationNo($systemNumber,
    $data,
    $data,
    $val,
    $data,
    $data,
    $array1,
    $array2,
    $array3,
    $array4);
```

I have a Type mismatch at the parameter 3

Some one got this kind of issue before?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:**
When I give an array at the first parameter I get *Type mismatch* at the parameter 7 :(

**EDIT2:**
I have no idea if that's from here, but it's exactly the same case
[PHP BUG](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48061&thanks=6)

Comment: If the prototype parameters start counting with zero the 3rd one should be a Boolean but you're passing 10 which of course is not a Boolean.

Comment: hank you Dave for your answer, but the third parameter can be the second $data or first $val. $data's type is int (I think the cast is automatique in this case) and $val in a bool :)

Comment: @Dave look at it again. The _fourth_ paramter is a boolean (and it's still the fourth parameter, whether you start counting at 0 or 1 - or 100). The fourth parameter passed in in the PHP is also a bool.